# gitattributes and the binary option

Tags: git

In the gitattributes you can specify that a specific file type should be treated as binary, e.g.

```
*.myExt binary
```

From:

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

This means that no line ending conversion will be applied or that textual diffs will be produced.

But what happens if I need to merge the content anyway? Will git try to merge it or simply skip all file types listed as `binary` in the gitattributes file?

Its not clear from:
http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

if file types marked as *binary* will be merged (meaning that git will try to do a merge/report possible conflict or simply skip this type off file).

Comment: By merged, you mean....?

Answer (score 5):

If you mark a file as `binary`, then it is not automergeable.  If two branches both change the file then git will refuse to perform the merge and will simply mark the file as a conflict:

```
% cat .gitattributes
foo.txt binary

% git merge branch
warning: Cannot merge binary files: foo.txt (HEAD vs. branch)
Auto-merging foo.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

However, if you want to allow the files to be automergeable but still keep the other effects of the `binary` attribute - namely, removing CR/LF conversion from the implied `-text` attribute, and removing diff'ability from the implied `-diff` attribute, then you can *set* the `merge` attribute:

```
% echo 'foo.txt binary merge' > .gitattributes

% cat .gitattributes
foo.txt binary merge

% git merge branch
Auto-merging foo.txt
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 foo.txt | Bin 112 -> 112 bytes
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```